Junit 5 (Jupiter) suddenly giving <terminated> error in Eclipse
I am currently working on a school project and have run into an issue. I coded the first part of the project and just to ensure everything is going well so far, I run my first test which instead of opening the JUnit Runner window and showing the green or red bar, nothing appears and I get this message in the console 
I've done three other projects with the exact same set-up as I am using now and have had absolutely no error running tests so I am very confused on why this is happening all of a sudden? I thought I may have set up the Maven project wrong but I went back to my other projects that I've already completed and submitted and now they too are doing the same thing with my test files even though everything was working fine last week. I've looked at a few different places for the cause and have been unsuccessful in fixing it so far. I have also tried a new workspace and completely reinstalling both Java JDK and Eclipse. Still unsuccessful. Here is my code for both the Appointment.java file and AppointmentTest.java file as well as how we were requested to have the files set up!. Any help is appreciated!
Appointment.java
/*************************
 * Name:    Summer Bernotas
 * Course:  CS-320 Software Testing, Automation, and Quality Assurance
 * Date:    June 5th, 2024
 *************************/

package Appointment;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.Date;

public class Appointment {
    private final String aptID;
    
    private final static AtomicInteger initializeAptID = new AtomicInteger();
    
    private final static byte DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 50;
    
    private String aptDescription = "DEFAULT";

    ////////////////
    // initializes and creates the Appointment constructor setting exceptions the description length. 
    // The appointment ID is also initialized and verified to only each having 10 characters. 
    ////////////////
    public Appointment(String aptDescription) {
        this.aptID = String.valueOf(initializeAptID.getAndIncrement() % 10);
        
        
        if (aptDescription == null || aptDescription.length() > DESCRIPTION_LENGTH) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Description can not be left blank and can only be " + DESCRIPTION_LENGTH + " characters long");
        } else {
            this.aptDescription = aptDescription;
        }
    }
    
    ////////////////
    // initializes getters for Appointment class
    ////////////////
    public String getAptID() {
        return this.aptID;
    }
    
    public String getAptDescription() {
        return this.aptDescription;
    }
    
    
    ////////////////
    // initializes setters for Appointment class
    ////////////////
    public void setAptDescription(String aptDescription) {
        if (aptDescription == null || aptDescription.length() > DESCRIPTION_LENGTH) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Description can not be left blank and can only be " + DESCRIPTION_LENGTH + " characters long");
        }
        
        this.aptDescription = aptDescription;
    }
    
}

AppointmentTest.java
package Test;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

import Appointment.Appointment;


public class AppointmentTest {
    
    @Test
    public void aptDescriptionLengthTEST() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            new Appointment("Description that is too long for the required argument length amount");
        });
    }
}



How is your project laid out? Where is the main class in it and where are the tests? Is it using modules, intentionally or otherwise? Is anything showing in the Problems View?

Our professor gave us a tutorial on how he wanted the Maven project set up, I added a photo to my question so you can see it exactly! I have not done anything in the AppointmentService.java and AppointmentServiceTest.java files yet!

Where are the JUnit 5 jars?

It seems Eclipse uses embbed junit4. Make sure to use valid @Test annotation (import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test) + (add jar definition into pom.xml) and configure Test runner: JUnit5

@Valijon This worked! I actually feel so dumb, thank you so much. My last project I solely used import org.junit.Test without issue. I appreciate you!

You are mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5)!!! That will not work!
